# Javascript unit testing - stub the data in a success callback

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, qunit

I'm writing a javascript test for my UserRepository.

I want to stub the data in the success callback function of the $http object.

User Repository code:

```
function UserRepository($http) {

    return {
        getUsers: function () {
            $http({ url: '/GetUsers' }).success(function (data) {
                //populate users
            });
            return users;
        }
    };
}
```

My test code:

```
    var httpStub = function() {
        return new {
            success: function(callback) {
                var array = [];
                array.push({ forename: 'john', surname: 'smith' });
                callback(array);
            }
        };
    };

    var userRepository = new UserRepository(httpStub);
    userRepository.getUsers();
```

The error i'm getting is "the object is not function" which i think is happening where my httpstub returns the object literal containing the success function, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem. The httpStub was doing

```
return new{
    success : function .....
}
```

When there should have been no new keyword e.g:

```
return {
    success : function .....
}
```